# is there anyway to search in database with finger print?

Tags: android, fingerprint

it was my question is there any way to store finger print in MySQL database
as a column so that we can retrieve data from database using fingerprint and using android app for this .

for first question is it possible to store image of finger print ? if yes i think maybe it is possible to save base 64 image of finger print but I'm not completely sure it will work or not.
if someone help me on this I will be very happy : )

Answer (score 0):

The Fingerprint data is stored by the android system in the phone at a secure location which is not accessible. You can write an app that gets and stores a fingerprint to authenticate the user but it will store in the android system.

Also, I feel that this is the right way. The very fact that you can store fingerprint data defeats the purpose of the fingerprint authentication.